# Redirect 404 error to custom 404 page

Tags: redirect, zend-framework, routes, http-status-code-404

I have a problem with my 404 page in a Zend Framework 1 project.

In case of route, action or controller error my application return 404 error. The only problem is that I want my link to change in something like www.exemple.com/error404.html. So let's say I have this link:

> http://www.exemple.com/some/something/dfsf

My application return 404 error, but the link remain the same. I would like that my link from above to redirect to :

> http://www.exemple.com/error404

In my ErrorController I have the following code:

```
public function errorAction()
{
    $errors = $this->_getParam('error_handler');

    switch ($errors->type) {
        case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ROUTE:
        case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_CONTROLLER:
        case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ACTION:

            // 404 error -- controller or action not found

            $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(404);
            $this->view->message = 'Page not found';

            break;

    }
    $this->view->exception = $errors->exception;
    $this->view->request   = $errors->request;
}
```

I try to do a redirect to a page created by me, but the redirect code is 302 and I need 404.

```
   public function errorAction()
{
    $errors = $this->_getParam('error_handler');

    switch ($errors->type) {
        case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ROUTE:
        case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_CONTROLLER:
        case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ACTION:

            // 404 error -- controller or action not found
            $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(404);
            $this->view->message = 'Page not found';

            //redirect to a 404 page
            $this->_redirect('/error404');
            break;

    }
    $this->view->exception = $errors->exception;
    $this->view->request   = $errors->request;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A 404 cannot also be a redirect, the two are mutually exclusive. If all you want to do is render your `error404` template, do this from the error controller (or modify the existing error action template).

See also Google's recommendations on soft 404s: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/181708

Comment: Actually I already  change my 404 page template content, my problem is the link that I need it to be something like this www.exemple.com/404.html. Thanks